# Lint imported object destructuring

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have this code:

```
import {
  Column, Entity, JoinTable,
  ManyToMany, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
```

I want it to be linted like so:

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
```

I know I can do it with prettier, but I don't want to run prettier, just to fix this one thing. All else is good with eslint. How can I make this formatting happen? The obvious choice would be [object-property-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline), but I have it configured like so:

```
'object-property-newline': [
  'error',
  { 'allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine': false },
],
```

And it doesn't help. Actually it just doesn't format destructuring. I tried like so:

```
const a = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar',};

const {foo, bar,} = a;
```

And it got linted to:

```
const a = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
};

const {
  foo, bar,
} = a;
```

So how can I make lint format my destructured objects?

And I want it to be

```
const {
  foo,
  bar,
} = a;
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline?

Comment: Import declaration syntax is not destructuring, and it doesn't use objects. Notice the aliases are declared with `as`.

Comment: @Bergi ok, sorry I misnamed it. But I hope by overall question is clear

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't see any option where it would help. Do you know of any?

Comment: I believe so. Thank you!